# Difference between "pyVmomi" and "vSphere Automation SDK for Python"?

Tags: vsphere, pyvmomi

When I was searching for [pyVmomi](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi) (Python SDK for the VMware vSphere API) doc/examples I found the [vSphere Automation SDK for Python](https://vmware.github.io/vsphere-automation-sdk-python/vsphere/7.0.2.0/) page. The name sounds like another vSphere SDK but the APIs are quite different from pyVmomi. Is it pyVmomi wrappers which may be much easier to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

vCenter servers currently serve up two main API services:

- [vSphere Web Services API](https://code.vmware.com/apis/968), SOAP based, integration point for pyvmomi (and the vSphere Management SDK)
- [vSphere Automation API](https://developer.vmware.com/docs/vsphere-automation/latest/), REST based, integration point for the vSphere Automation SDK

The SOAP API is basically at parity with the vSphere UI, whereas the REST API is fairly new and mainly VM and VCSA focused in terms of available functionality.